# Is there a way to find out which package was responsible for a DependecyPackageInstallation?

Tags: dependencies, package-management

Is there a way to find out from which package installation a certain package was installed as dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check `/var/log/apt/history.log` for a log entry.

Also, there are several ways to check for reverse dependencies:

```
apt-cache rdepends packagename
```

Will show you all packages that depend on `packagename`. Also those that are not installed, though. Better would be:

```
aptitude why packagename
```

This might require you to install [aptitude](http://packages.ubuntu.com/aptitude) [image: Install aptitude]

if everything else fails, try to remove the package in question and look at which other packages would be removed because of your decision. Remember to answer "n" to the "are you sure?" question.

Answer (score 3):

In a Terminal, try `aptitude why $package`.